# If G is an open subset of a metric space, is it true that $\text{int}(\bar{G}) = G$?

Tags: metric-spaces

If G is an open subset of a metric space, is it true that $\text{int}(\bar{G}) = G$?

I have not been able to find a counter example or a proof. Any hints?

Comment: Look at $G=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X=(a,b)\cup (b,c)\subset \mathbb{R}$. $\overline{X}=[a,c],$ and $int(\overline{X})=(a,c)\ne (a,b)\cup (b,c).$